# which parameter describes an enum?

Tags: c++, parameters, enums

i want to call my method with the following call:

```
fillGridWithAttributes(AEnumVendor::VENDOR1);
```

how do I "expect" this call in my method fillGriddWithAttributes?

i tried:

```
void fillGridWithAttributes(AEnumVendor type) {}
void fillGridWithAttributes(enum AEnumVendor type) {}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: First one should work

Comment: first one should work :)

Comment: They both will work, I still can't understand what is the question, since the OP says he _tried_ both approaches...

Comment: my `AEnumVendor` is defined in an other class. i'd just to prefix this one.. thx :)

Comment: @jntme, I see. Well yes, then you just have to use `class_name::enum_name`. However, make sure to include such information into the question next time, since it's important to give the right answer. Also, if you solved the problem yourself, don't hesitate to answer your own question, in order to share your solution with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my AEnumVendor is defined in an other class. I'd just to prefix this
>   one...

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are legit options.

Answer (score 0):

`fillGridWithAttributes(AEnumVendor::VENDOR1 type) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
   void fillGridWithAttributes(AEnumVendor type) {}
   void fillGridWithAttributes(enum AEnumVendor type) {}
```

will work, but calling the function ned to be changed as

```
   fillGridWithAttributes(VENDOR1);
```

Even

```
   void fillGridWithAttributes(int type) { }
```

will work. But it is always better to have AEnumVendor instead of int.

Comment: It depends: if `VENDOR1` is defined in `enum class AEnumVendor`, then you do need the scope. But as SingerOfTheFall commented, the question omits such details